# phpMyAdmin - I can't export SQL Tables? Syntax is given though?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

All I am trying to do is export a local hosted SQL Database (WordPress).

If I click on the table > export > quick - display only the minimal options > and select 'SQL' format this is the start of the code that is displayed:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.4.10
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost:8889
-- Generation Time: Feb 24, 2017 at 03:49 AM
-- Server version: 5.5.42
-- PHP Version: 5.6.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `kerequip!`
```

and a bunch of other code - what am I doing wrong?

All I wanted was the usual .sql download of the database?

Comment: What is the other code that's in the file? Is there a table definition and data, but just not what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are seeing is the contents of the .sql file that would be exported. It looks like somehow your phpmyadmin got configured to display the export as text instead of downloading the file. To download the file, select custom for the export method. Then in the output section select save output to file. That is the only setting you need to change. Then run the export and it will correctly download the file. Once you have done this once, the quick export should work correctly again.